# Does "scientific research" only include ones about physics, biology, etc

Tags: meaning

> Students who have worked on a scientific research project outside of high school classes are welcome to submit a research supplement via Slideroom.

According to dictionary, "scientific" means "of, relating to, or exhibiting the methods or principles of science." And, the "science" means

> 1. knowledge about or study of the natural world based on facts learned through experiments and observation.

However, it also means

> 2. the state of knowing :   knowledge as distinguished from ignorance or misunderstanding
> 3. a department of systematized knowledge as an object of study.

So, I think I can submit a research paper on the subject of East Asian Geo-political relations. Is this right?

Comment: It really depends of if the people asking for the paper are interested in a paper on a _scientific topic_, or a paper written using the _scientific method_. If it's the latter, then you might be right; if it's the former, though, then your paper might not be the paper they are looking for. I'm inclined to think they are wanting a paper on a scientific topic, and that this doesn't include political science, but I'd have to know more about the nature of the solicitation to be sure. From an English perspective, though, you're right, it can be ambiguous. More context is needed to know for certain.

Comment: You could submit it to a place that cares about _political_ science. But 'Science' magazine would not care at all about your paper. Before you do anything, check the journal or conference to see if there are other papers like yours. Also, better to ask this on academic.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Political Science** is a legitimate area of study that meets the criteria you listed above. However, as indicated, it may not be what your instructor is looking for. How about asking that person (those people?) if your proposal would be satisfactory before embarking on a massively time-consuming project?